# Laravel: Why does pluck('name', 'id') return all user's name?

Tags: laravel

I found a bug in my program, and I realise `User::find(1)->pluck('name', 'id')` returns a collection of all `names` I have in my db.

Why? `User::find(1)` is returning only one user object, shouldn't pluck work on that instead?

Other findings:

`User::find(1)->get()->pluck('name', 'id')` returns the same result.
But that's because `User::find(1)->get()` returns all users too. Again not intuitive imo.

`User::find(1)->take(1)->pluck('name', 'id')` however works.

Comment: try this `User::where('id',1)->pluck('name', 'id')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're executing the query twice. You want to do this to get name and ID of just one user:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

Instead of:

```
User::find(1)->pluck('name', 'id')
```

Comment: Is there any chance I can use pluck on a `User` object? I'm using pluck globally for formatting the `select` options, and I have a relationship that already returns the correct `User` object.

Comment: @resting if you have an object, just create an array or collection manually from the object with `$array[$user->id] = $user->name;`. Or you can use `array_pluck([$user], 'name', 'id')`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `pluck()` after `find()`, because it will just run query to get id from all rows.

**Do something like this instead:**

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

**Or something like,**

```
$user = User::find(1)->name;  //if you need to fetch just one column
```

Answer (score 1):

[`pluck`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) :

> Get an array with the values of a given column

It does not filter the data

Instead `find` method you can use `whereId`

```
$user = User::whereId(1)->pluck('name', 'id');
```